# Specify the generator name (e.g., nx generate @nrwl/workspace:library)--Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, web-development-server

I am learning web develoment. In angular, I am trying to generate a new component but there's an error `Specify the generator name (e.g., nx generate @nrwl/workspace:library)` after I write `ng generate component homeimgs`

How do I solve this error?

[Here is the picture of the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ftbF.png)

Comment: Did you install Nx instead of the Angular CLI?

Answer (score 0):

If you are usign Nx, try use this command in CLI:

```
nx g @nrwl/angular:component *componentName* --project=*projectName*
```